# values not changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have to show the name prop as initials. It shows the initials fine on mount. but when I later change the value in the parent component. It doesn't change values. I tried computed as well but it shows that I didn't use the computed property. What am I missing here?

got this two errors

```
 'computedInitial:' is defined but never used  no-unused-labels
 'get' is not defined
```

code

```
<template>
<div>
    {{ showInitial }}
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
  data() {
    return {
      showInitial: null,
    };
  },
  computed(){
      computedInitial:{
        get() 
        return this.name
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    let initials = this.computedInitial.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
    this.showInitial = ((initials.shift() || "") + (initials.pop() || "")).toUpperCase();
  },
};
```

Comment: your computed option should be like `computed:{computedInitial:{get(){return this.name}}}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim did that. still the values aren't changing when I change the name in parent component

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in the computed property. Also, you only need a `computed` property to show the initials of the `name`:

```js
const comp = Vue.component('comp', { 
  template: '#myComp',
  props: {
    name: { type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    computedInitial: {
      get() { 
        let initials = this.name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
        return ((initials.shift() || "") + (initials.pop() || "")).toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit("set-name", "user test");
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data () {
    return {
      name: "test user"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setName(newName) { this.name = newName; }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
  <comp :name="name" @set-name="setName" />
</div>

<template id="myComp">
  <div>
    {{computedInitial}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: yeah caught the typo. but still ain't not updating the initials even if I update the name in the parent component

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight you need to use ``emit`` to change a ``prop`` value, and use computedInitial as the property to show. I updated the answer.

Comment: you're right a computed that returns only the prop is useless

Answer (score 0):

your computed option should be like

```
 computed:{
       computedInitial:{
          get(){
            return this.name

            }
        }
    }
```

But I recommend to define `showInitial` as another computed property in order to be changed :

```
<template>
<div>
    {{ showInitial }}
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
  data() {
    return {
     
    };
  },
  computed:{
           computedInitial:{
              get(){
                return this.name
 
                }
            },
        showInitial (){
               let initials = this.computedInitial.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
               return ((initials.shift() || "") + (initials.pop() || "")).toUpperCase()
        }
        },
};
```

Comment: so I should remove the showInitial from data?

Comment: Yes you should !